# Apache Camel: get consumer endpoint information in bean method called by the Camel route

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel

I have multiple databases, all containing the same table `Data`. I want to read from them, input all `Data` elements into the `MyBean` method `@Handler public Data updateData(Data data)` and write back the output of the method.

```
from("jpa://Data?persistenceUnit=persUnit1").to("direct:collector");
from("jpa://Data?persistenceUnit=persUnit2").to("direct:collector");
from("jpa://Data?persistenceUnit=persUnit3").to("direct:collector");
...

from("direct:collector").bean(new MyBean()).to("jpa://Data?persistenceUnit=destinationUnit");
```

However I need the information from which source the `Data` element came (e.g. the name of the persistence unit) within the bean for validation. What's the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a header

```java
from("jpa://Data?persistenceUnit=persUnit1")
    .setHeader("dataSource", constant("dataSource1"))
    .to("direct:collector");
from("jpa://Data?persistenceUnit=persUnit2")
    .setHeader("dataSource", constant("dataSource2"))
    .to("direct:collector");
```

Answer (score 0):

The exchange object provides the necessary information to about the "from" endpoint (of current exchange):

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#getFromRouteId()

It's quite usual to put id on routes (but also on endpoints)

```
from("jpa://Data?persistenceUnit=persUnit1")
  .routeId("ComingFromRouteA")
  .to("direct:collector");
```

This way, you can know where you come from, using:

```
exchange.getFromRouteId()
```